# How to store the current HTML+PHP page code as a string and use it to generate a PDF file

Tags: javascript, php, report, pdf-generation, mpdf

```
<button id="PRINT" class="btn btn-theme btn-register margintop10 pull-left"
type="button" onclick="return printReport();">PRINT</button>

// Here is the class instance which is used to print the PDF file. 
    $orderController = new orderController();
    $orderController->BuildPDF($html);
```

1) Most important doubt, I don't know how to retrieve the current HTML+PHP page code as a string in both languages: javascript or PHP. Which functions and server variables do we have o fulfill this purpouse?

2) Not sure if I should link the button to a **javascript function** and there somehow store the current page code and call a separated php class.

Or if I should set an attached link (**href=""**) to the button and call a different PHP(sending the page code) file to run the report generation.

Comment: It's taking me too much time, really need a hand here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For getting file contents via JS**

So, you might try to have a PHP file called something like retrieve.php, and in that file you can do:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['file']) && file_exists($_GET['file'])) {
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
}
exit;
```

and in your JS, you can simply do an ajax request to call `retrieve.php?file=<your path to this file>`; assuming you know where the file you want to get as a string is located.

**For getting file contents inside of PHP**

Similarly, in PHP you can use the same `file_get_contents($path);` function:

```
<?php
// Include stuff to get the controller objects.

$path = 'path/to/printablefile.php';
$html = '';
if (file_exists($path)) {
    $html = file_get_contents($path);
}

$orderController = new orderController();
$orderController->BuildPDF($html);
```

As for applying this to your problem, you should have your current page fetch the code/page you're wanting to print.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for details.

Comment: Keep in mind this solution is not for collecting rendered content. If you want a rendered version of your code, your option is to use file_get_contents with a URL path or other complex things; however, this will only grab the rendered HTML and not PHP that's embedded in the file.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for replying. Unfortunatelly I would need a solution that bring me back HTML + PHP printed. The $html variable must be a string containing the rendered page.

Comment: When you say HTML + PHP you mean PHP that's executed to render the HTML? Because I interpreted your question as you wanted the non-rendered HTML and PHP of a file. If your answer is yes, you can can still use the methods above, but instead of supplying a path, you supply a URL. 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-examples like in that example.

Comment: Yes PHP + HTML, sorry the misunderstanding.